# Take and Skip in SQL Server and EF

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, skip-take

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I'm using EF. I have a table and a SQL view(the view displays rows from this table plus some unimportant data(~ 1000 records)) with ~ 400.000 records.
When I display the data in EF it takes 25 seconds

```
    MVCAppEntities db = new MVCAppEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.vvItem.OrderBy(n => n.Code).Skip(20).Take(40).ToList());
    }
```

In SQL Server Management Studio this query takes 0-1 seconds

```
select  code, quantity, name, price
from (
    select *,
           row_number() over(order by code) as rn
    from vvItem       
 ) as T
where T.rn between 20 and 40
```

**Q** : Why is the EF query so slow ? should I make a SP to do the Skip and Take ?

Comment: `where T.rn between 20 and 40` is not the same as `Skip(20).Take(40)`

Comment: Did you try running SQL profiler to see what SQL query actually gets executed by your EF query?

Comment: I only want the query to be executed fast. How can I make the EF query to work faster ?

Comment: The SQL query is executed fast, only the EF query is slow. How can I test(and improve) the EF execution time ?

Comment: What is `db` and when / where did you created that instance?

Comment: I updated my code. db is declared the first time you call the ASP.NET Controller(I'm using EF).

Comment: Are you sure the table is indexed on "code" column? Also in your c# code you have db.gest_vvItem, while in your SQL code you have 'vvItem'

Answer (score 1):

Is it running faster in subsequent calls? It might just be a first time issue. Have a look at this link.

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3706-optimizing-performance.aspx